# iPhone Internationalization

Tags: iphone

How do I internationalize the following code:

```
NSLog(@"Feature: %@, Cost: %f, ID: %@",[product localizedTitle],
          [[product price] doubleValue], [product productIdentifier]);
```

...with the code below:

```
NSLocalizedString(@"Feature", @"");
NSLocalizedString(@"Cost", @"");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"myKey",nil),[product localizedTitle], [[product price] doubleValue], [product productIdentifier]]);
```

In your Localizable.strings file:

```
"mykey" = "Feature: %@, Cost: %f, ID: %@";
```

Make sure you have an entry in each locale, including English.

Answer (score 1):

For localizing price...

```
NSNumberFormatter *moneyFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init];    
[moneyFormatter setNumberStyle:kCFNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[moneyFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];    
[moneyFormatter setLocale:product.priceLocale];

NSString *defaultString = [moneyFormatter stringFromNumber:product.price]];
[moneyFormatter release];
```

ProductIdentifier is unique and it is same for all languages, for strings use product.localizedTitle and product.localizedDescription properties.

Comment: You have to use moneyFormatter because in US price is in "$" symbol and for other countries it is different.

Comment: Hi Chandan thanks for giving your kind consideration. I will also need the answer u gave to me.